# Wordpress menu + jQuery slide or animate?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make jQuery play nice with my WP navigation. My goal is to hide the navigation until the logo is clicked and have the menu slide in from the left, much like this example but with click instead of hover: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/UIElements/SlideOutMenu/#

Does anyone know a simple way to hide/reveal a whole div within WP, possibly with .animate or anything else?

My working site: http://armandwho.com/site

THANKS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the div to `width: 0px;`  then you can call something like this

```
$(function(){                  //this is short for $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#clickhere").click(function() { 
    $("#animate1").animate({ width: "100px" }, 1000); 
 });
});
```

that will animate , showing the div , you can apply .animate to change css setting

make sure jquery is added to the head of the page , also make sure `#clickhere` is set to the id of what your clicking and `#animate1` is set to the id of the div you want to show